# Any way to tell getAttr is at the last element of a path?

Tags: fuse

I'm writing a read-only FUSE file system that abstracts access to a remote file system. The remote file system requires an user ID, a token and a file ID to produce a file.

If I have mounted my FUSE file system on /mnt/rfs and an program tries to open the file /mnt/rfs/user/token/fileid FUSE will trigger three getAttr invocations, one for /user, one for /user/token and one for /user/token/fileid.

Is there any way to detect from inside the getAttr invocation that this particular call is for the last element in the path? Obviously, if I know how my service works, I can just fake the directories for the first two elements, then download a file to some local tmp storage using the user/token/fileid info. But this is hacky and fragile.

Comment: Not sure, but don't think there's a way to identify that the first two *getattr* calls are a part of a broader context to verify the path of the third, final call. But first, why is faking the first two level directories considered a hack? If it's a good abstraction of the remote file system as a local one, it's not a bad idea. Second, if the three elements shouldn't be separated, why not use one directory level with some format to represent the three fields, ex: user#token#fileid/?

Comment: It's not a bad abstraction, I had just hoped that there was a generic way to do this. But I ended up doing what you suggest, essentially handling it on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 0):

There's no generic way to do it. Handle it on a case-by-case basis.